# Quartz.net Scheduler using clustering

Tags: c#, .net, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

I 'm using the clustering option and I have some problems with it:

1. When I using with two machines the jobs that I created runs in the beginning without connection to theirs definition.
   for example: if I defined the job to run once a ten second it can run every two second on the beginning and only from the 2th running it's correctly - every ten second.
2. The two machines take the same job in the same minute (but not in the same millisecond) and run the job twice together, I tried to use the lock handler property but maybe I didn't define it well..

This is my code:

```
NameValueCollection properties = new NameValueCollection();

properties["quartz.scheduler.instanceName"] = "TestSchedulerNECH";
properties["quartz.scheduler.instanceId"] = "instance_one";
properties["quartz.threadPool.type"] = "Quartz.Simpl.SimpleThreadPool, Quartz";
properties["quartz.threadPool.threadCount"] = "200";
properties["quartz.threadPool.threadPriority"] = "Normal";
properties["quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold"] = "60000";
properties["quartz.jobStore.type"] = "Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreTX, Quartz";
properties["quartz.jobStore.useProperties"] = "false";
properties["quartz.jobStore.dataSource"] = "default";
properties["quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix"] = "QRTZ_";
properties["quartz.jobStore.clustered"] = "true";
properties["quartz.jobStore.lockHandler.type"] = "Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.UpdateLockRowSemaphore, Quartz";
properties["quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateType"] = "Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.SqlServerDelegate, Quartz";
properties["quartz.dataSource.default.connectionString"] = "Server=localhost;Database=mydb;Trusted_Connection=False;User=admin;Password=123456";
properties["quartz.dataSource.default.provider"] = "SqlServer-20";


ISchedulerFactory sf = new StdSchedulerFactory(properties);
IScheduler sched = sf.GetScheduler();

string schedId = sched.SchedulerInstanceId;

for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
{

IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<SimpleRecoveryJob>()
    .WithIdentity("job_" + i, schedId)
    .RequestRecovery(false)
    .Build();

ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
    .StartAt(DateBuilder.FutureDate(10, IntervalUnit.Second))
    .WithCronSchedule("0/10 * * * * ? *")
    .ForJob(job)
    .EndAt(DateBuilder.FutureDate(3, IntervalUnit.Minute))
    .Build();

sched.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
}

sched.Start();
```

Someone can help me?

Comment: One quick check you should do is to make sure the clocks on both machines are synced.

Comment: The clocks on both machines are in sync - it's the first thing we checked... more than that - we have situation of the same job run in the same machine with incorrect interval.

Comment: The value of 'quartz.scheduler.instanceName' must be the same on all instance and each 'quartz.scheduler.instanceId' must be unique. Is it correct in your configurations ?

Comment: Yes, The value of 'quartz.scheduler.instanceName' is the same on all instance and each 'quartz.scheduler.instanceId' is unique

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old thread, but if we want to disallow concurrent execution, we have to add the DisallowConcurrentExecution attribute to the job class.

Comment: I believe this attribute only prevents a single task from being run in parallel on a single machine - e.g. a long running task scheduled to repeat at short intervals. It does not influence, or prevent, TWO machines (such as in a load balanced scenario) from firing the same job at the same time, as I have recently experienced.  For that, you need to persist jobs and use unique machine identities, as per this guys instructions: https://mikaelkoskinen.net/post/quartz-net-cluster-sql-azure-asp-net